# ASP.NET Theme stylesheet rendering

Tags: asp.net, rendering, themes, stylesheet

When a page with theme is rendered, the stylesheets link tags in the given theme are rendered right before the closing head tag.  Does anyone know of a way to change that?  Is there a way that I could have those tags be placed right after the opening head tag?

I know it can be down with jquery by just selecting all the link tags and placing it right after the opening head tag, but is there a way to set it on the server end?

**Clarification**
Let us say I have a single css file (themed.css) in my theme.  In that css file, I have a single style definition for a div tag with an id of test:

```
#test {background-color:red; color:white;}
```

Let us also say I have a second css file (standard.css) that is NOT in my theme, but it has another definition of the div tag with an id of test:

```
#test {background-color:yellow;}
```

I have my page to use the theme, and I have a handwritten link tag to use standard.css.  When the page is executed, the link tag for standard.css is before themed.css.  When that happens my div tag with id of test has a red background and white forecolor.  If I want the themed.css to apply and then standard.css to overwrite the necessary properties (yellow background with white forecolor), I would want themed.css and THEN standard.css.  I can't do that because ASP.NET places the theme files right before the closing head tag.

I don't want to have to know that my theme's css files are the nth link tag in my head tag and then manual change any index whenever i may add a new css file outside of my theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a little checking in Reflector, and found something you may find interesting. The framework calls the `SetStyleSheet` method of a `PageTheme`-derived object to inject link controls in the header. This code snippet shows the relevant logic:

```
int num = 0;
foreach (string str in this.LinkedStyleSheets)
{
    HtmlLink child = new HtmlLink { Href = str };
    child.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    child.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    if (this._styleSheetTheme)
        this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(num++, child);
    else
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(child);
}
```

**Translation**? StyleSheetThemes inject the style sheets at the ***beginning*** of the header tag, and Themes inject the style sheets at the ***end***.

This is consistent with the intended difference between themes and stylesheet themes; that is, that a theme always wins when there is a conflict between the skin and the control settings. Sure, a style in a non-themed .CSS file using the `!important` attribute could still override a theme style, but the positioning of the CSS files within the head tag strategically facilitates override-ability stylesheet themes.

Note that you can have *both* a stylesheet theme and a regular theme. Naturally, leave to the stylesheet theme things you design to be override-able, and to the theme things that should not be overridden.

One final observation is that the method is `internal` and non-virtual, so interfering with these two options would take some kung-fu-MMA-mad-reflection skills, and is probably not in the best interest of stability or maintainability.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as your `head` element has `runat="server"` you can rearrange the collection in Page_PreRender:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlCollection container = this.Page.Header.Controls;
        foreach (var control in container.OfType<System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink>().ToArray())
        {
            container.Remove(control);
            container.AddAt(0, control);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But that is with the notion that there is a static number of link tags in your head.  I was more curious if there was a way one could override the flow of placing the link tags there is the first place, and not just rearranging them after the case.

Comment: At the moment PreRender() event happens, links to all CSS-files found in the current theme folder are already in Header.Controls collection. So my code will rearrange both static and dynamic (added by ASP.NET) links.