# Child asp.net controls being appended but how?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This one has be stumped. I'm doing some work on a legacy ASP.NET WebForms app and in the html head element I'm getting some stylesheets being included before the closing tag and I can't find the code that's doing it.

I need my new stylesheets to appear after these ones, so need to find the code that's inserting them and change to InsertAt(0) so they appear at the opening of the element.

I've searched for the stylesheet names, I've looked in the master page code, I've looked in the global.asax.cs and done wide-ranging searches for Controls.Insert, etc, but no joy. Am I going mad? Some how these stylesheets are being programatically added.

Does anyone have any tips for where to look?

Comment: Have you checked to see if they are being inserted via Javascript?

Comment: They're visible in the HTML, so by my understanding it's got to be the server.

Comment: True, if you're seeing it in the actual content sent by the server and not just when browsing the DOM it would have to be inserted on the server side.

Comment: What are the styles?  They might be added by ASP.NET controls such as `Menu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using themes? If so any css file in a theme directory is added.

Comment: Yes! Ah, I see now. Can this behaviour be customised, do you know? Thanks Josh. I'll go read up on themes, it's been a long time since I played with them.

Comment: This question provides the follow-on info needed to work around the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917187/asp-net-theme-stylesheet-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Is `Page.Header` being modified in code-behind for the page or its master(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow along in the debugger (or by using IO) and determine when it happens? Is that stuff in the header before the master file inits, loads, etc.  Figuring out exactly when the stylesheet appears would help narrow the issue down.

As an additional place to look, some 3rd party controls may add extra stylesheets to your head.  You won't see the stylesheet by doing a find in source code if all you have are object files.

You might also see hints if you look in the stylesheet's actual code.  What styles is it adding? Are *they* anywhere in your code?