# Control ASP.NET theme css link order placement

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a mix of css in themes and universally (non theme specific) files. I would like the theme css files to be included first before my custom css files - how can this be done (see below, the StyleSheet.css file is a theme file which is always included last, I want it included first)

```
<!-- CSS needed on every page -->

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App_themes/PageLayout.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App_themes/EmbedFonts.css" />

<!-- CSS placed by ASP.NET -->

<link href="App_Themes/DarkTheme/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><title>
```

Note: I am using master pages with themed Web forms.

Comment: How are they being added now? Are you using master pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT :** Since you're only using themes to pull CSS, use Page property StyleSheetTheme instead of Theme. That should render your theme CSS links first instead of last, making them overridable. This was confirmed in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917187/asp-net-theme-stylesheet-rendering). 
[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx#ThemeSettingsPrecedence) explains the difference between the two properties, alluding to how the stylesheet links would be rendered. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed this would solve the problem, however I rather like using themes with their own individual css files.

Comment: Are you using the Theme property or the StyleSheetTheme property?

Comment: I am using themes, set at the top of each Web Form.

Comment: Are you using other elements of asp.net's theming (eg templating, etc) or are you only using the Theme property to set the stylesheet?

Comment: I am only using the Theme property to set the stylesheet(s)